# Run breakpoint (lm) detection in parallel in R

Tags: r, dplyr, breakpoints, doparallel, multidplyr

I am doing about 80000 time series breakpoint detection calculations in R. I have all these extremely different time series where I cannot apply ARIMA models so I am calculating a linear model per time series, then extract the breakpoints and use the fitted results of the regression to calculate the trend coming from the last breakpoint.

 
[image: Example of one time series]

In the above example the algorithm would detect three breakpoints (one incline, one rather flat and one decline). It's a perfect fit for my needs but running 80k breakpoint calculations once a week sequentially is just too much overhead, hence I am trying to implement this by using parallel processing in R.

In this example (find link to data below) I am calculating the breakpoints sequentially which is taking about 24h for all 88k.

```
df.subset <- read.csv("dfsubset.csv)"
start <- Sys.time()

All.Breakpoints <- df.subset %>%
nest(-CONC_ID) %>%
mutate(bps = map(data, ~breakpoints(ACT_QTY_new ~ Index, data = .)))

Sys.time() - start
```

In this code snippet I am running the detection on 10 time series (on my mac) which is taking *47 seconds*. I would guess that parallelising should reduce this benchmark time to about 1/4 pf the time.

Below I have listed three ways I have tried to parallelise the calculation but I cannot get the nested apply to work in a parallel setting.

With the parallel package

```
clus <- makeCluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(clus, {library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(magrittr)})

myfunction <- function(df.subset) {
All.Breakpoints <- df.subset %>%
nest(-CONC_ID) %>%
mutate(bps = map(data, ~breakpoints(ACT_QTY_new ~ Index, data = .)))
return(All.Breakpoints)
}

clusterExport(clus, "myfunction")

do.call(bind_rows, parApply(clus, df.subset, 1,{function(r) { 
myfunction(r[1]) }}))
```

With the multidplyr package:

```
library(multidplyr)
cluster <- create_cluster(4)
set_default_cluster(cluster)

four <- function(x) {
All.Breakpoints <- x %>%
nest(-CONC_ID) %>%
mutate(bps = map(data, ~breakpoints(ACT_QTY_new ~ Index, data = .)))
return(All.Breakpoints)
}

cluster_assign_value(cluster, 'four', four)
save <- df.subset %>% partition(CONC_ID) %>% map(four(.))
```

With the parallel package but other grouping

```
library(parallel)
cl <- detectCores()

group <- df.subset %>% group_by(CONC_ID) %>% group_indices
df.subset <- bind_cols(tibble(group), df.subset)

cluster <- create_cluster(cores = cl)

by_group <- df.subset %>%
partition(group, cluster = cluster)

by_group %>%
# Assign libraries
cluster_library("tidyr") %>%
cluster_library("dplyr") %>%
cluster_library("strucchange") %>%
cluster_library("purrr") %>%
# Assign values (use this to load functions or data to each core)
cluster_assign_value("df.subset", df.subset) 

cluster_eval(by_group, search())[[1]] # results for first cluster shown 
only
cluster_get(by_group, "df.subset")[[1]]

start <- proc.time() # Start clock
sp_500_processed_in_parallel <- by_group %>% # Use by_group party_df
group_by(CONC_ID) %>%
mutate(bps = map(data, ~breakpoints(ACT_QTY_new ~ Index, data = .))) 
%>%
collect() %>% # Special collect() function to recombine partitions
as_tibble()   # Convert to tibble
time_elapsed_parallel <- proc.time() - start # End clock
time_elapsed_parallel
```

Link to file:

http://www.filedropper.com/dfsubset

I appreciate your ideas and feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking a question and describing the problem will solve it for yourself most of the time... I figured out that mutate does not work anywhere (**keep me honest, Stackoverflow**) in parallel in R.

I therefore changed to using *do* and distribute the load via *multidplyr* and get a decrease in compute time of about 50% when going from 1 to 4 cores and to 25% of total time when going from 1 to 8 cores.

Code below.

```
## parallel
cl <- detectCores()
cl

df.cluster <- df.subset

cluster <- create_cluster(cores = cl)
cluster

by_group <- df.cluster %>%
partition(CONC_ID, cluster = cluster)
by_group

by_group %>%

# Assign libraries
cluster_library("strucchange")
cluster_eval(by_group, search())[[1]] # results for first cluster shown only

start <- proc.time() # Start clock

cluster.processed <- by_group %>%
                     do(model = breakpoints(ACT_QTY_new ~ Index, data = .)) %>%
                     collect()

time_elapsed_parallel <- proc.time() - start # End clock
time_elapsed_parallel

rm(by_grou)
gc()

Predictions <- cluster.processed %>%
mutate(SegmentedForecast = map(model, fitted))
df.fitted.vector <- as.data.frame(rowwise(Predictions[,3])) .
```